# cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'T'

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

I hope this is something really simple that I am just completely missing, but I can't seem to figure out what needs to be changed here.

> cannot convert from `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>` to `T`

The compile error is coming from this block here, specifically item.DataItem:

```
    public List<ImportItem<T>> ProcessReportResult(CSVTable resultData, ICollection<ImportItem<T>> data, Func<T, IEnumerable<string>> keyFilter)
    {
        WriteLog("{1}{0} records found.{1}", resultData.Rows.Length, Environment.NewLine);

        //key = Order Number; value = Order ID
        var idDictionary = resultData.Rows.Select((row => row.Split(','))).ToLookup(id => id[0], id => id[1]);

        idDictionary.ForEach(id => WriteLog("Input Id = {0} - Matching record Id = {1}", id.Key));

       var processList = data.Where(item => idDictionary.Contains(keyFilter(item.DataItem))).ToList();

        processList.ForEach(item => item.Id = idDictionary[keyFilter(item.DataItem)]);

        return processList;
```

The declaration of DataItem is coming from within this class here:

```
public class ImportItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public IEnumerable<string> DataItem
    {
        get; set; 

    }

    private bool visible;
    public bool Visible
    {
        get { return visible; }
        set
        {
            visible = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Visible");
        }
    }

    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Id
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public Status Status { get; set; }

    public ImportItem(T item)
    {
        DataItem = (IEnumerable<string>) item;
        visible = true;
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Please show the exact statement that gives this compiler errors and show the relevant declarations (`data`, `keyFilter`).

Comment: There is no reason for your class to be generic, the way it is right now. You are only using the type parameter at one specific point (`ImportItem`) and even then, you're essentially asserting that `T` will be `IEnumerable<string>`. Did you mean to declare `DataItem` as `T`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is keyFilter? I'm guessing it returns IEnumerable, which means that there's no Contains() overload on a Dictionary for it. You probably want the following:

```
var processList = 
data.Where(item => keyFilter(item.DataItem).Any(key => idDictionary.ContainsKey(key))).ToList()
```

Comment: _"I'm guessing"_ - that's what comments are for. Let OP respond first.

Comment: Sorry - I'm quite new here and didn't realise that. I'll make sure it doesn't happen again! :)

Comment: No problem, I think you're on the right path too. It's just a waste of your time if it turns out to be something else.